# Is there a better way of getting retrieving 'closeTime' , which is within a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple counter that starts when user clicks a button on the pop up and I store that value in `openTime`, when user closes the popup I store the current time in `closeTime` but due to `closeTime` being within a function, I'm not sure the best way to retrieve that value so that I am able to subtract it from `openTimer`

I want to avoid global variables. Right now I am setting `closeTimer` to local storage then retrieving it to do the calculations, but I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this.

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  var openTime = localStorage.getItem('myCat')
  var closeTime = localStorage.getItem('closeTime')
  console.log("OPEN TIME:",openTime,"CLOSE TIME",closeTime)
  var timelaps = openTime - closeTime
  localStorage.setItem('timelaps', timelaps);
  console.log("TIMELAPS OF POPUP BEING CLOSED",timelaps)

  if (port.name === "popup") {
    console.log("popup has been opened")
    
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function () {
      console.log("popup has been closed")
      var closeTime = localStorage.getItem('myCat')
      localStorage.setItem('closeTime', closeTime);
      console.log(closeTime)
    });
  }
  
});
```

Comment: You need to define "better" in objective terms. Do note that `openTime` is declared in the scope of the function of the `onDisconnect` listener. Have you tried just referencing `openTime` in that function?

Comment: if you dn't want to use globals, what other choice to you have? localStorage seems fine, though you should test for actual values and normalize to numbers or 0

Comment: And shouldn't you be removing listeners on disconnect?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I want the subtraction to happen, after the user has opened the popup again, that's why I wanted a way to retrieve closeTime

Comment: @Kinglish What do you mean?

Comment: I have not worked with chrome extensions, but it seems like you're creating a new onDisconnect eventListener every time a popup is open (I htink) because it is happening inside of the onConnect event listener. maybe i'm wrong